# Multi users app with InteractiveComplexHeatmap

Tags: r, shiny, server, multi-user, complexheatmap

I am writing a shiny app using InteractiveComplexHeatmap that is running on a shiny server. Everything works fine until another user generates a new heatmap. This will freeze the first plot (the "selected sub-heatmap" window is not updated anymore when interacting with the original heatmap). Only the latest generated heatmap works as expected. No error is displayed.

The problem seems to occur even with the official examples posted online e.g.
https://jokergoo.shinyapps.io/interactive_enrichedheatmap/

If you load it in 2 different windows, you can select the heatmap cells only in the last one.

Do you know if their is a way to make InteractiveComplexHeatmap work with several competing users online?
Thanks a lot for your help